# StackOverflowError in XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion

Tags: eclipse, editor, stack-overflow, unhandled

Eclipse has just today taken to giving me an error every time I try to create a new file. A window pops up saying

Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError

when I open up the error in the log, it shows:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.StructuredDocumentRegionProxy.setStructuredDocumentRegion(StructuredDocumentRegionProxy.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelUpdater.changeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelUpdater.java:440)
```

---

Also, in the error log, I see something title "Unable to create editor ID org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor: The file does not exist."
Click on that, I get:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The file does not exist.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:237)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:559)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:979)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.connect(CompilationUnitDocumentProvider.java:1243)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4213)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1451)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2563)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2536)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1395)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3200)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2642)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3218)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.handleDeferredEvents(PartStack.java:1213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LayoutPart.deferUpdates(LayoutPart.java:400)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.handleDeferredEvents(PartSashContainer.java:1409)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LayoutPart.deferUpdates(LayoutPart.java:400)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.handleDeferredEvents(WorkbenchPage.java:1495)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.deferUpdates(WorkbenchPage.java:1485)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditors(WorkbenchPage.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.closeEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorPane.doHide(EditorPane.java:61)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.close(PartStack.java:537)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.close(EditorStack.java:206)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.close(PartStack.java:120)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:83)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:269)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:278)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder.access$1(DefaultTabFolder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder$1.closeButtonPressed(DefaultTabFolder.java:71)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PaneFolder.notifyCloseListeners(PaneFolder.java:631)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PaneFolder$3.close(PaneFolder.java:206)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1598)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:261)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

and, in addition, whenever I finally close eclipse, I get this:
http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/3204/eclipseerror.jpg

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A StackOverflowError is almost always caused by infinite recursion. In other words, a bug. Increasing available heap space will not fix it.

I have updated the question title to make it more likely that someone who knows this code sees and provides a definite answer. Absent that, you should open a bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?classification=WebTools

Make sure to include information what version of Eclipse you are using and what actions lead to StackOverflowError. Focus on StackOverflowError as the second exception is likely caused by it. Bad things happen when JVM aborts code due to exceeding stack depth limit.

Comment: There was an xml issues. Odd, seeing as it was copied straight from the Android dev site, but between that and an update, the problem has been resolved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you still have the XML file that causes this problem and can reproduce it after the update, make sure to open a bug at the above URL with that file as the attachment. No XML file should cause a StackOverflowError.

Comment: <item android:id="@+id/add_player"
          android:title="Add Player" ></item>  

    <item android:id="@+id/finish_round"
          android:title="Finish Round" ></item>

was the segment that was doing it. The copied code had the item element as <item ------------ /> which as far as I know should have worked fine, but for whatever reason, on my machine caused eclipse to have problems.

Comment: Ok. Great, but remember to open a bug with this info in order to reach the people who would be able to fix this problem.